# Accessing server managaer in windows 8.1

Tags: windows-8.1, iis, .net-framework, iis-8

I am new to windows 8.1 (skipped it, upgraded my private from 7 to 10). I need to access the server manager, in order to add roles to an installed iis 8.5 manager, so I can add .net 4.5 to my iis .net framework list in the application pool.

How do I access the server manager in windows 8.1 and add roles to my iis?

Comment: You don't. It's not a server. Neither is the server manager available in Windows 7 or Windows 10. At least not out of the box from what I know. What you can do is use the "add features" dialog to add that feature, assuming your edition supports it.

Comment: Go to Control Panel, add/remove programs and add the features that you want. Windows 8.1 is for personal use and not a server version.